# Forward kinematics of spherical parallel manipulators with revolute joints

Tags: mobile-robot, kinematics, forward-kinematics, robot-model

I found an article that can help in my investigations.

[Forward kinematics of spherical parallel manipulators with revolute joints](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4601715)

The problem is solved for the following system of vectors, which is shown in the figure.

[image]

The methodology described in the article allows, using simple numerical calculations on a computer, to determine the angles $\psi$, $\psi$'and $\phi$, $\phi$'.

All other angles ($\alpha_2$,$\alpha_3$,$\alpha_4$,$\alpha_5$,$\mu$) are known.

The coordinates of points $B_1$,$B_2$,$B_3$ and $C_1$,$C_2$,$C_3$ are also known.

I do not know how, knowing these parameters, it is possible to determine the coordinates of points $A_1$,$A_2$,$A_3$.

In the same article on page 525 there is such a sentence:

[image]

But I do not understand how to do this.
I ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors $v_i$ are restored very simply.

For example, vector $v_1$.

First we need to rotate the $C_2$ vector by the angle $\phi_1$ around the $C_1$ vector. This way we get the intermediate vector $v*_1$.

And then rotate this vector by the angle $(\alpha_2 - C_1 \cdot C_2)$ around axis of rotation $(v*_1 \times C_1)$.

Vectors calculated in this way are similar to the calculated data given in the publication.

For the remaining vectors, the principle is similar.